# How to derive this conditional distribution function for a Restricted Boltzmann Machine?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I am following along Ian Goodfellow's new Deep Learning book and, reading the [last chapter](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/generative_models.html), I am confused about equations 20.7-20.9.

We have a joint distribution function, $P(v,h)$, and we are interested in finding the conditional distribution function, $P(h|v)$. If, from the definition of the Restricted Boltzmann Machine,

$$
P(v, h) = \frac{1}{Z} \exp(b^Tv +c^Th + v^TWh)
$$
where $Z$ is the normalizing constant,

$$
Z = \sum_v \sum_h \exp(b^Tv +c^Th + v^TWh).
$$

$P(h|v)$ is then (copied from the chapter):

\begin{align}
P(h|v) &= \frac{P(h,v)}{P(v)} \tag{20.7}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{P(v)}\frac{1}{Z}\exp(b^Tv +c^Th + v^TWh) \tag{20.8}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{Z'}\exp(c^Th + v^TWh) \tag{20.9}
\end{align}

That last step is where I am confused. What is $Z'$ -- there is nothing about that in the text? Is it some other constant that serves as a new normalizing constant or is it actually a derivative with respect to either $v$ or $h$? Could someone fill in some missing steps?

Answer (score 2):

P(h/v) implies v is given/known. So 1/Z' should lump together all the constant terms i.e. exp(b'v)/(P(v) * Z)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what happens here is treating P(h|v) as a "function of h, knowing v". Everything what has not a h in itself is treated as a constant part and put in a new normalizing constant - Z'.

Intuitively - computations of a partition constant - Z or Z' - are intractable. That's why you use e.g. a Monte Carlo method to approximate it. That's why - in my opinion - author wasn't concentrated on full scrutiny during writing this set of equations.